# Error Code: 1064. Cannot insert data into database

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-insert

The full error code is:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''CPU', 'null', '0', '0', '0'")' at line 2

I'm trying to add product data from my PHP webpage, and getting this error. So I tried doing it manually on MySQL and I get the same error.

Here is a copy of the database and the code that I'm using to insert data:

[image]

```
    INSERT INTO store_db.components (product_name, price, description, manufacturer, socket, date_added, type, form_factor, expansion_slots, sata_ports, capacity)
       VALUES ('Intel Core i7 4790K','250',
         'agsdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg ','Intel','LGA 1150',now()),
         'CPU', 'null', '0', '0', '0'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redundant `)` after `now()`. Get rid of it and you should be OK:

```
INSERT INTO store_db.components (product_name, price, description, manufacturer, socket, date_added, type, form_factor, expansion_slots, sata_ports, capacity) VALUES ('Intel Core i7 4790K','250','agsdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg ','Intel','LGA 1150',now(), 'CPU', 'null', '0', '0', '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra parenthesis:

```
now()), 'CPU',
```

should be

```
now(), 'CPU',
```